# Xcode - element Constraint to another element

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to know why will appear the situation of the picture?
I have already used the standard coding that should work on the app layout alignment which should be perfect.
And I don't know why it doesn't work.

`@"V:[individualCheckBox]-%lu-[businessDistributionCheckBox]"`

The mean is between individual CheckBox and business Distribution CheckBox will have constraint? but I don't know why in  All css and Individual have space

code:

```
    selectNatureButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[selectIndividualButton]-15-[selectNatureButton]-15-|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(selectIndividualButton,selectNatureButton)]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[individualLabel]-15-[selectNatureButton]"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(individualLabel, selectNatureButton)]];
    [selectNatureButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[selectNatureButton(==120)]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(selectNatureButton)]];
    [selectNatureButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[selectNatureButton(==40)]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(selectNatureButton)]];



    moreIndividualButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[moreIndividualButton]-15-|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(moreIndividualButton)]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[selectIndividualButton]-15-[moreIndividualButton]"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(selectIndividualButton, moreIndividualButton)]];
    [moreIndividualButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[moreIndividualButton(==150)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(moreIndividualButton)]];
    [moreIndividualButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[moreIndividualButton(==40)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(moreIndividualButton)]];

    individualLayoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[individualCheckBox]-%lu-[businessDistributionCheckBox]", (([selectedIndividualMutableArray count] + 1) * 60 + 60)]
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(individualCheckBox, businessDistributionCheckBox)];
    NSLog(@"ans: %lu", (([selectedIndividualMutableArray count] + 1) * 60 + 60) );

    [scrollView addConstraints:individualLayoutConstraint];`
```

Comment: show code in question instead of screenshot!! and when need to show screenshot don't put link, you can directly upload picture in question or answer!

Comment: @Lion, ok I show code in question